# Where and how to use CASE WHEN SQL multiple sub queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am curious as to where and how I would use the `CASE` statement in the query below but only applying to the outer query i.e the final results.  I want my `CASE` statement to reflect those values so do i.e `CASE WHEN 'TOTAL OH INV' - P1.[REM PLAN QTY] < = 100 THEN 'URGENT'` and so on for different qualifications.  Would this start directly after my first select?

```
DECLARE @number as int
SET     @number = CASE
                  WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Monday'
                  THEN 56
                  WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Tuesday' 
                  THEN 57
                  WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Wednesday' 
                  THEN 58
                  WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Thursday' 
                  THEN 59
                  WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Friday' 
                  THEN 60
                  END;


SELECT          P1.PLANT_CODE,
                P1.STOCK_CATEGORY,
                P1.MATERIAL,
                M1.DESCRIPTION,
                M1.DEPT,
                M1.RMH_PRODUCT_DIVISION,
                M1.RMH_GENDER_AGE,
                P1.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE,
                P1.PERIOD_CODE,
                P1.REQUIREMENTS_DATE,
                P1.VERSION_IND_FLAG,
                P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                P1.SIZE_LITERAL,
                P1.[ORIGINAL FCST QTY],
                P1.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY,
                P1.[REM PLAN QTY],
                P2.FUTURE_FCST,
                SUM(I1.ON_HAND_QUANTITY) AS 'TOTAL_OH_INV'
FROM


(SELECT         P.PLANT_CODE,
                P.STOCK_CATEGORY,
                P.MATERIAL,
                P.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE,
                P.PERIOD_CODE,
                P.REQUIREMENTS_DATE,
                P.PLANNED_QTY AS 'REM PLAN QTY',
                P.VERSION_IND_FLAG,
                P.SIZE_LITERAL,
                P.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY,
                P.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                P.PLANNED_QTY + P.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY AS 'ORIGINAL FCST QTY'
 FROM           VW_PLANNED_REQMNTS_TXT P
 WHERE          P.PLANT_CODE IN ('6040','6041')
 AND            P.STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60385000','A60385003')
 AND            P.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE IN ('00','01','ZU','Z2')
 AND            P.REQUIREMENTS_DATE < GETDATE() - @number
 AND            P.PLANNED_QTY > 0) AS P1

 LEFT OUTER JOIN      

 (SELECT
                SUM(P.PLANNED_QTY) AS 'FUTURE_FCST',
                P.MATERIAL,
                P.TECHNICAL_INDEX
 FROM           VW_PLANNED_REQMNTS_TXT P
 WHERE          P.REQUIREMENTS_DATE >= GETDATE()
 AND            P.PLANNED_QTY > 0
 AND            P.STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60385000','A60385003')
 GROUP BY       P.MATERIAL,
                P.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                P.SIZE_LITERAL) AS P2
 ON             P1.MATERIAL = P2.MATERIAL
 AND            P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX = P2.TECHNICAL_INDEX

 LEFT OUTER JOIN 

 (SELECT        I.ON_HAND_QUANTITY,
                I.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                I.MATERIAL,
                I.STOCK_CATEGORY,
                I.PLANT_CODE
  FROM          VW_INVENTORY I
  WHERE         I.STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60385000','A60385003')
  GROUP BY      I.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                I.MATERIAL,
                I.STOCK_CATEGORY,
                I.ON_HAND_QUANTITY,
                I.PLANT_CODE) AS I1
  ON            P1.MATERIAL = I1.MATERIAL
  AND           P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX = I1.TECHNICAL_INDEX
  AND           P1.PLANT_CODE = I1.PLANT_CODE

  LEFT OUTER JOIN

  (SELECT       M.MATERIAL, 
                M.DESCRIPTION,
                M.DEPT,
                M.SUB_SEGMENT,
                M.RMH_PRODUCT_DIVISION,
                M.RMH_GENDER_AGE,
                M.RMH_CATEGORY
    FROM        VW_MM_MATERIAL M) AS M1

    ON          P1.MATERIAL = M1.MATERIAL


  GROUP BY      P1.PLANT_CODE,
                P1.STOCK_CATEGORY,
                P1.MATERIAL,
                P1.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE,
                P1.PERIOD_CODE,
                P1.REQUIREMENTS_DATE,
                P1.[REM PLAN QTY],
                P1.VERSION_IND_FLAG,
                P1.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY,
                P1.SIZE_LITERAL,
                P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                P1.[ORIGINAL FCST QTY],
                P2.FUTURE_FCST,
                M1.DESCRIPTION,
                M1.DEPT,
                M1.RMH_PRODUCT_DIVISION,
                M1.RMH_GENDER_AGE


 ORDER BY       P1.MATERIAL,
                P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX;
```

Comment: poorly worded, I guess I am asking HOW within this multiple query do I place the CASE/WHEN when I only want it to reflect the the first SELECT values

Comment: Can you please edit your question and make it understandable?

Comment: By "first" are you asking for like a TOP 1 record or something else?

Comment: apologies, I am still new to the terminology.  By first I mean the very first select statement, which represents all of the others, they are all subqueries of it.  Do I use CASE in the beginning of this statement or at the end, before the GROUP BY/ORDER BY which are using the same data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally do this by wrapping my entire select statement in another select then adding my case statement to that.  I.e.

```
SELECT field_list, CASE WHEN 'TOTAL OH INV' - P1.[REM PLAN QTY] < = 100 THEN 'URGENT' 
FROM (put your existing select statement here)
```

This way all of your calculations are performed prior to your CASE statement filtering only by the final results.

Comment: I think you were able to understand what I was saying, reading your output, that is exactly what I am looking for, I just wasn't sure how to tell exactly where to place the CASE but it seems to work where you are pointing.

Comment: I guess what I am saying is where do you put a CASE statement when you are running a query with multiple sub queries?  The only data I want applied is the main select i.e P1.... P2....M1...